# IntelliJ Scala Case Class Indentation

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

This question may have been asked, but I could not find a suitable answer, so I'm posting this as a question here. The problem is that when I create a new case class, the indentation looks so wierd.

```
case class SomeCaseClass(
                         id: Int
                        )
```

I would however prefer it to be like this:

```
case class SomeCaseClass(
  id: Int
)
```

I would just like to know which option in IntelliJ would allow me to get away with this awkward indentation.

Comment: Check out the [scalafmt](http://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) plugin for IDEA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Scala Plugin's case class indentation is absurd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880677/intellij-scala-plugins-case-class-indentation-is-absurd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to do this. Here is what needs to be done:

1. If you are on a Mac, select IntelliJ -> Preferences
2. Select Editor -> Code Style -> Scala
3. In the "Wrapping and Braces" tab, uncheck "Indent braced arguments"

Hope this helps someone that might run into the same issue!