# How can I change the behavior of my Scala classes Indentation in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, class, intellij-idea, indentation

The default Scala style in IntelliJ often will begin my newlines at a non-recommended location with too many indents/spaces. An example is outlined below:

[image: default scala styling intellij]

How might I configure my Scala plugin or IntelliJ styling to indent my case classes like below, when I hit enter. Example below:

[image: correct scala styling]

If I were to obey the default Scala plugin conventions I will get:

[image: Incorrect styling case class indentiation]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26880974/2707792) solve your problem, or is it somehow outdated?

Comment: Yes. This worked still. It even worked with method signatures which is also recommended for long argument lists. Thank you!